# The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "X.X.X". Got "X.X.X"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I am getting error:

> The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "10.15.1". Got "12.14.1"

How do I fix this?

Comment: If this is a 3rd party module ask the maintainer.  It might just be shortsightedness or it might not actually be compatible.

Comment: Which module is it?  Please provide a link to this module on NPM.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the `package.json` file there is an "engines" section.

```
"engines": {
  "node": "10.15.1"
}
```

Update it to the expected node version.

```
"engines": {
  "node": "12.14.1"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NVM commande (Node Version Manager), to use other Node version.

Try : `nvm use 12`

Answer (score 0):

change setting in  "pom.xml", file path is :hadoop-3.3.1-src\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-applications\hadoop-yarn-applications-catalog\hadoop-yarn-applications-catalog-webapp

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
<artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<workingDirectory>target</workingDirectory>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>install node and yarn</id>
<goals>
<goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
</goals>
<phase>generate-resources</phase>
<configuration>
<nodeVersion>v8.11.3</nodeVersion>   <!-- change here, my setting v12.22.12-->
<yarnVersion>v1.7.0</yarnVersion>
</configuration>
</execution>
<execution>
<id>yarn install</id>
<goals>
<goal>yarn</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```